# Upload de arquivos

Tags: upload, amazon-aws

Estou testando a conta free do S3 e o Glacier, Subi os arquivos no S3 para que ele seja transferido automaticamente para o Glacier, porem faz 2 dias já e não mostra os arquivos que eu subi no s3, demora mesmo para aparecer ou tem algum problema?

Comment: uploads no s3(putObject) tem leitura imediata logo após a escrita, ou seja, logo após o upload os arquivos já ficam disponíveis no bucket. Verfique se você está na mesma regiao onde foi feito o upload, se não deu nenhum erro durante o upload e também se os arquivos não foram transferidos para Glacier e removidos do bucket.

Comment: Pude notar que o S3 subio os arquivos, porem o glacier não puxou, sabe como sei se houve erro ?

Comment: Isso depende da regra de ciclo de vida que você definiu para o seu bucket. Existem vários tutoriais falando sobre isso, da uma olhada nesse aqui: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/